# Self installing Windows Service leave install logs behind. How to disable this?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-services

I am using the following code to self-install a Windows Service (this code is located in Program.cs). When I use "servicename.exe --install" the service installs just fine, however some install logs are left behind. servicename.InstallLog and InstallUtil.InstallLog. Is there any way to disable completely the logging of these files?

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            string parameter = string.Concat(args);
            switch (parameter)
            {
                case "--install":
                    ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                    break;
                case "--uninstall":
                    ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
         new Service1()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper` handles the functionality of the Installutil.exe (Installer Tool) (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.managedinstallerclass(v=vs.110).aspx). And InstallUtil accepts argumens to redirect or disable logs, according to documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool)

You can try to change `InstallHelper` arguments like this to disable logs. Seem to work fine:

```
string parameter = string.Concat(args);
switch (parameter)
{
    case "--install":
        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/LogFile=", "/LogToConsole=true", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location});
        break;
    case "--uninstall":
        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", "/LogFile=", "/LogToConsole=true", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This method works only for the LogFile. The InstallState file is still being generated upon service install. Is there any way to disable it aswell?

Comment: @JohnSwarley There was nothing about .InstallState in the initial question, and my sample project didn't create it because there were not installer inside. I guess the only way to remove InstallState is to delete it manually after installing the service. This file could be important for uninstall process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624848/net-windows-services-and-installstate-file-is-it-really-needed

Comment: @JohnSwarley You could also play with `/InstallStateDir=[ directoryName ]` parameter. Try adding `/InstallStateDir=` argument right before `/LogFile=`. But I'm afraid that it will just use current directory by default.